# как отправить видео через python на другой сайт

Tags: python

```
import pytube
link = input("Enter the video link: ")

yt = pytube.YouTube(link)
videos = yt.get_videos()


s = 1

for v in videos:

    print(str(s)+ ". "+str(v))

    s +=1

n = int(input("Enter the number of the video:"))
vid = videos[n-1]

des = input("Enter the destination: ")
vid.download(des)
```

Вот я скачал видео из YouTube

Теперь надо отправить видео которые я скачал на dump.uz юных нет апи надо загрузить видео и взять ссылка из dump.uz

Comment: подробней опишите что вы хотите сделать. Откуда видое появляется и в каком виде вы хотите "отправить". Если как файл, то не имеет значение видео это или нет. Для каждого сайта свой код может потребоваться (есть ли api, какие ограничения).

Comment: можна так сделать?

Comment: если загрузка у вас работает (вы успешно сохранили файлы на диск), то можно не упоминать как вы именно загрузили файлы. Достаточно сказать, что у вас есть файл на диске с заданным именем. Сейчас у вас вопрос получается: *"как загрузить файл на указанный файлообменник, если тот не предоставляет явного  API"* Подход можно попроовать: посмотреть какие запросы делаются, когда вы руками выполняете загрузку. Повторить эти запросы в Питоне.  См. [Как и на каком языке можно написать программу, которая автоматизирует ручное заполнение информации в окне браузера](https://goo.gl/duTQdM)

Comment: ne ponyal :(( xz